# Python console: difference between sys.version() and os.system("python -V")

Tags: python, pycharm, version, platform, sys

When I use Pycharm, whose default python interpreter is set to be python 2.7.14. When I run the integrated console in Pycharm several line of code bellow, the python versions are confusing. Could someone explain what's the difference between these two commands?
[image]

Comment: Can you try `os.system("which python")`?

Comment: Are you sure that pycharm is set to work with python 2.7.14? I think that `os.system("python --version")` gives the version of the system default python interpreter, whereas `platform.python_version()` gives the version of the interpreter which calls this function.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, it gives: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python

Comment: @LouisSugy I'm sure the python in this project's venv/bin/python2.7 is 2.7.14 . After I set this up, I use the pycharm integrated python console to run those codes.